# Why does discriminated union work fine in one case, but doesn't work in another very similar one?

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

<sup>*A.S.: The question is not about "Why is there an error?", but rather about "Why does the error go away if I barely change it?".*</sup>

I have a relatively simple logic of creating parameters for a regex validator function that gathers the regex from either the combination of `source` and `flags` string inputs, or the regex input directly; it also takes a validation config in both cases. Some inputs are optional, some are required.

Here is how it looks like:

```
type Options = { foo: 'bar' }

type ArgsRegExp = [first: RegExp, second?: Options]
type ArgsString = [first: string, second?: string, third?: Options]
type Args = ArgsRegExp | ArgsString

interface Params {
  readonly pattern: RegExp
  readonly options?: Options
}

function getParams(args: ArgsRegExp): Params
function getParams(args: ArgsString): Params
function getParams([first, second, third]: Args): Params {
  if (first instanceof RegExp) {
    return {
      pattern: first,
      options: second,
//             ^^^^^^ Error!
    }
  }

  return {
    pattern: new RegExp( // weird new lines are explained in the playground 
      first,
      second
//    ^^^^^^ Error!
    ),
    options: third,
  }
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/mqqpRm)*.

There is an error here: the `second` arg is always `string | Options | undefined`, and thus it is not assignable in neither cases (it must be `Options | undefined` in the first case and `string | undefined` in the second).

**This error is expected**, and (if I understand correctly) is related to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581

However, what is *not* expected is that a very similar piece of code (here's [the diff view](https://www.diffchecker.com/40LI73Om/) of them) works fine without producing any assignability issues, because it perfectly narrows down the items as you'd wish:

```
type Common = 'c'

type ArgsRegExp = [first: 'a0', second?: Common]
type ArgsString = [first: 'b0', second?: 'b1', third?: Common]
type Args = ArgsRegExp | ArgsString

interface Params {
  readonly custom: string
  readonly common?: Common
}

function getParams(args: ArgsRegExp): Params
function getParams(args: ArgsString): Params
function getParams([first, second, third]: Args): Params {
  if (first === 'a0') {
    return {
      custom: first,
      common: second,
//            ~~~~~~ No error?
    }
  }

  return {
    custom: // weird new lines are explained in the playground
      first +
      second,
//    ~~~~~~ No error?
    common: third,
  }
}
```

*[Try it](https://tsplay.dev/w2QkVW)*.

What's up with that? **Why does this work, but the original example doesn't?** I get that the types are different, but I can't pinpoint exactly which difference contributes to the two examples behaving differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
type Options = { foo: 'bar' }
type ArgsRegExp = [first: RegExp, second?: Options]
type ArgsString = [first: string, second?: string, third?: Options]
type Args = ArgsRegExp | ArgsString
```

the type `Args` is *not* a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  Discriminated unions in TypeScript require their discriminant property to be or include [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types). You are switching on the first tuple element, which is either a `RegExp` or a `string`, neither of which are literal types.  So that element is not seen as a discriminant, and therefore no narrowing is done when checking that element.

On the other hand, in

```
type Common = 'c'   
type ArgsRegExp = [first: 'a0', second?: Common]
type ArgsString = [first: 'b0', second?: 'b1', third?: Common]
type Args = ArgsRegExp | ArgsString
```

your first element is either of type `"a0"` or `"b0"`, both of which are literal types.  So `Args` here *is* a discriminated union, and you can check the first element and get the narrowing you want.